# How to retain original origin point

Tags: edit-mode

I have a model which I had the 3D cursor and origin set up to a particular position which allowed me to use the exported (gLTF) model in Flight Simulator without having to reposition it's position above ground level (the origin point naturally aligns with the ground level).
I noticed that when I added some more mesh cubes where I had to set the origin to the center to allow for good rotation, that the original origin point for the entire model was 'lost'.
Is there a method to 'store' the origin point so that it can be 'restored'?
Thanks.

Comment: Please give more information. Did you add the cubes in _Edit Mode_ or _Object Mode_? If there are several objects, how did the new cube origins affect the origin of the original model? And if you join the cubes with the model with Ctrl+J, then the combined model will always take the origin (and also the name) of the **active** selected object, the one with the brighter outline. So maybe you should join the cubes to the original model, not the model to the cubes?

Comment: Oh, and if the cubes are added in _Edit Mode_: you can select a cube inside the mesh, set the 3D cursor to its center with Shift+S > _Cursor to Selected_ and then set the _Pivot Point_ for rotation to the 3D cursor. This way the cube can be rotated around its center without the need to change the origin.

Comment: Thanks. All in EDIT mode. And yes  joined cubes (select all meshes and ctrl J) into a single mesh. I can't remember where the origin of the original model ended up as I decided to remove everything except the new bits create a separate blender file containing just the new bits reload the original and append the new.  I have learned something new (ie if the cubes are added in Edit Mode: you can select a cube inside the mesh, set the 3D cursor to its center with Shift+S > Cursor to Selected and then set the Pivot Point for rotation to the 3D cursor. ). Thanks again

Comment: So if you don't have the model with the correct origin anymore, don't know where the original origin point was and it wasn't something like a certain vertex or the center of a certain part of the mesh, then there is no way to retain the original origin point - because you are free to change the origin on objects and Blender doesn't store where they were before (apart from the _Undo_ function of course).

Comment: if you still have a copy of the original object you can use its origin location to move the new object's origin

Comment: I did NOT save the project with the origin in the wrong place. When I added the new meshes I noticed that the origin for the model had moved so did not save. I then removed all the bits which were the original model and saved the then new meshes only as a new blender file then (re)loaded the original blender file and appended the new blender file and moved the object to where I wanted it to be. So I didn't have a problem BUT I just wanted to find out how to maintain the original origin in the future instead of creating two 'projects' and appending as just described.